# In frontend menu, the links are not popping out when in hamburger menu is clicked

Tags: magento2, frontend, topmenu

In magento 2 ..while responsive mode the hamburger menu gets displayed. but when clicking on the menu the hamburger menu is not popping out links. I don't know why.?

this is my sections.phtml file placed in

`E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\sections.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php

/**
*  General template for displaying group of blocks devided into sections
*/

$group = $block->getGroupName();
$groupCss = $block->getGroupCss();
$groupBehavior = $block->getGroupBehaviour() ? $block->getGroupBehaviour() : '{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}';
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames($group, 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="sections <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="section-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-items" data-mage-init='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupBehavior ?>'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html) && ($block->getUseForce() != true)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="section-item-title <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-title" data-role="collapsible">
                    <a class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-switch" data-toggle="switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="section-item-content <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?></div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: pass the site url to check if you can make it live on demo server

Comment: i am working offline.. just a beginner.. dont know about server and hosting and all

Comment: little harder to check , can be  CSS issue

Comment: i have not used any css with class name .nav ! can u help?

Comment: deleting this files make your menu work perfect ? because this files has no error..

Comment: its not working yet!

Comment: Then there are some css issues because this file has no error at all and can be  errors in some other files